Borel summation for extending the radius of convergence of a Taylor expansion
Suppose we know the Taylor expansion of a function $f$ that has poles at some points but none on the real axis; its radius of convergence is $R>0$.
Now, we want to compute $I(a)=\int_{0}^{a}f(t)\, dt$ with $a>R$. Note that we can't use the Taylor expansion of $f$ for any $t>R$ in order to compute $I(a)$.
Question: could Borel summation be a tool in such a use case ? I mean one could find an analytic continuation of $f$ on $[0:a]$ with a Borel sum, and thus use this analytic continuation for computing $I(a)$.
More generally, what are the options to compute such an integral $I(a)$ knowing the Taylor expansion of $f$ only for $|t|<R<a$ ? I have found this and indeed Taylor expand about a different point would allow to integrate outside $[0:R]$. However, I'm affraid it implies that we have to know the poles of $f$  in order to find the point to Taylor expand the function.
